# React testing library - Check button disabled attribute

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Okay, so I have this input field which requires `at-least` 10 characters, which enables the button which says `Save & Next`.

If `description.length < 10`, it stays disabled. This is working fine in the UI.
But I am unable to write a test for it.

```js
test(' Disables the save and next button if description < 10', () => {
    render(<StepOne />, { initialState });
    const input = screen.getByLabelText(/description/i);
    fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '123456' } }); //  Length < 10
    const button = screen.getByText('Save & Next');
    console.log(button.innerHTML);
    expect(button).toBeDisabled(true);
  });
```

Error:

```
expect(element).toBeDisabled()

    ❌ Received element is not disabled:
      <span class="MuiButton-label" />
```

I wonder what I am missing here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [`debug`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#debug), you will see how a disabled button is rendered by MUI:

```html
<button
  class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text Mui-disabled Mui-disabled"
  disabled=""
  tabindex="-1"
  type="button"
>
  <span class="MuiButton-label">Save & Next</span>
</button>
```

So, you can use [`.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to access the `button`:

```js
const button = screen.getByText('Save & Next').closest("button");
expect(button).toBeDisabled();
```

Comment: hmm, still did not work for me